# Connection problem Azure Managed Instance and Data Factory with Windows authentication

Tags: azure, windows-authentication, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have a Azure SQL Managed Instance and a Azure Data Factory V2.
 
Now I want to get a connection with Windows Authentication between a SQL database and ADF V2.
I added a Active Directory User with the "CREATE USER ... FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER" statement to the Managed Instance.
I tried it multiple times, but I don't get any connection.
Only this error message: "code:9056, message:Cannot connect to SQL Server".
I also tried a AD user that is AD admin at this server, same result.

When I try the same user with SSMS and authentication mode "Active Directory - Password", it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please install a selfhosted IR and use that to access your managed instance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime

Comment: I've installed a selfhosted IR. There are no problems with an SQL Server authentication, only with Windows authentication.